# I.i.d. Discrete Random variables with mean 0 and variance 1

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Given a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0,\ \mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$ consider the sum $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{X_k}$. Is it true that independently of the distribution of the sequence $\mid S_n-S_{n-1}\mid=1$ for all $n\geq 2$?

Comment: The body of the Question should be as self-contained as possible, certainly  not relying on the title alone to convey crucial information.  The "i.i.d." assumption (independent, identically distributed) nature of the random variables is mentioned only in the title, which may mislead the casual Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counter-example: $P(X=-\sqrt3)=1/4, P(X=1/\sqrt3)=3/4$